# Header Image in Visualforce PDF not displayed

Tags: visualforce, css, pdf, images

Image not getting displayed in PDF though I tried doing this.Can Anyone Please correct me what is wrong? I tried using it both in  div.header and in @page.Both doesn't work fine?

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="testpportunity1"   showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="PDF">

  <html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
        <head>
            <style  type="text/css" media="print">
                @page {

                    @bottom-center {
                        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                     }
                     div.header{
                        position:running(header);
                    }

                }

           </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            </body>

     </html>
      <div class="header">
        <img src="{!$Resource.IconSample}" width="25%" />
      </div>
                  <!--<apex:image url="{!$Resource.IconSample}"  width="220" height="150" />-->
                <br/>
                 <apex:outputText style="text-align:left; width : 100%;font-size: 16px;" value="Address"></apex:outputText><br/>
                 <apex:outputText style="text-align:left; width : 100%;font-size: 16px; " value="Street"></apex:outputText><br/>
                  <apex:outputText style="text-align:left; width : 100%;font-size: 16px; " value="City"></apex:outputText><br/>

                <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock >
                <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                              <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title=" Opportunity Information">
                    <table width="100%" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                          <apex:repeat value="{!oppList}" var="opp">
                        <tr>
                           <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080;">
                                OpportunityOwner
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.Owner.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080;">
                                OpportunityName
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.Name}
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080; ">
                                Account Name
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.Account.Name}
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080;">
                                Type
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 {!opp.Type}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080; ">
                                StageManagement
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 {!opp.Stage_Management__c}
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080; ">
                                Stage
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.StageName}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080;  ">
                                CloseDate
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.CloseDate}
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" style="color: #808080;  ">
                                Probability
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {!opp.Probability}
                            </td>
                        </tr> 

                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </table>
                    </apex:pageblocksection>
                    </apex:pageBlock>


                      <apex:pageBlock >
                       <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title=" Product Details">
                            <table width="800px" height="1200px" >
                            <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="i"/>
                                <tr style="background-color:{!IF(mod(i,2)==0, ' #C0C0C0', '#C0C0C0')};">
                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                                    <th>Total Price</th>
                                 </tr>
                                  <apex:variable value="{!i+1}" var="i" />
                                   <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="i"/>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!prodList }" var="prod">
                               <tr style="background-color:{!IF(mod(i,2)==0, ' #C0C0C0', '#C0C0C0')};">
                                        <td>{!prod.pricebookentry.product2.name}</td>
                                         <td> {!prod.quantity}</td>
                                            <td> {!prod.quantity}</td>
                                            <td> {!prod.TotalPrice}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <apex:variable value="{!i+1}" var="i" />
                                </apex:repeat>
                            </table>
                            </apex:pageblocksection>
                        </apex:pageBlock>
                        <style>

                </style>
                   </apex:form>
                   <apex:outputText >xyz</apex:outputText><br/><br/>
                   <apex:outputText value="order:" style="text-align:center; width : 100%;font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold ;  color :#000000"> </apex:outputText> <apex:outputText >Salsforce</apex:outputText><br/>
                 <apex:outputText > Visualforce</apex:outputText><br/>
                 <br/><apex:outputText style="text-align:left;font-weight: bold;" value="Best Regards,"></apex:outputText><br/>
                 <br/><div style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;">
                            <apex:outputText style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;"  value="Thank you"></apex:outputText></div>
                            <br/><br/><div style="text-align:center;font-size: 25px;">
                            <apex:outputText style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;"  value="SALESFORCE"></apex:outputText></div>

                   <p class="par">

                            This is Opportunity page.

                            </p>        

                  </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class testpportunity1{
 public List <Opportunity> oppList{get;set;}
  public List <OpportunityLineItem> prodList{get;set;} 
  public user cuser{get;set;}


public testpportunity1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
 oppList = new List <Opportunity>();
        oppList = [SELECT name, owner.name,Account.Name, stagename, amount,ExpectedRevenue,NextStep,LeadSource,Probability, CloseDate,Type,Stage_Management__c
                               FROM Opportunity
                               WHERE id = '789456123'];
    System.debug('opportunity list------->'+oppList);
    prodList =new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
     prodList = [SELECT PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, quantity, unitprice, totalprice
                                                    FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                                    WHERE OpportunityID='789456123'];
      cuser=[select id,Username,Signature__c from user where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
       System.debug('User list------->'+cuser);

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your visualforce page declaration you have the following:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" renderAs="PDF">
```

html-5.0 is not supported when rendering PDF's in Salesforce. Only html 4.2 is supported and CSS 2.1.

Your CSS begins with the following:

```
div.header {
            background: url("{!$Resource.IconAji}") no-repeat center center;
```

Off-hand, I don't recall that type of syntax being supported in HTML 4.2. You may need to change that and use a different syntax as that looks like CSS 3 to to me.

With PDFs it's best to use tables if you want them to render consistently and successfully.

**Edit**

In response to comments...

I looked in my code repository and here's an example of the proper way to add an image to a header:

```
@top-center {
        content : element(header);
     }

div.header {
    position : running(header) ;
}
```

in style classes, then to your page add:

```
<div class="header">
    <apex:image value="Image URL" />
</div>
```

**Edit 2**

Since your pages are wrapping and the number pagination in the footers is working as written, I think you need to do the following. Remove the div that contains your current header. Then, adjust your CSS to contain the image so it can also repeat at the top of each page. You may need to tweak this, but the CSS should look something like what's below. I'll add that if you encounter issues, one thing which might help would be putting the CSS in an external resource so you can reference the image's relative location to the external resource.

```
@top-center {
        content : element(header);
     }

header {
    position : running(header);
    content: img(src="{!$Resource.IconSample}", width="25%");
}
```

**Note:** I'm not positive the above syntax for the header content is correct. You may need to play with it to get it correct, but I do believe content is what you want to use. You could try replacing content with something like the following if it doesn't:

```
    background-image: url(src="{!$Resource.IconSample}", width="25%");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

See the [CSS 2.1 reference docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/changes.html#q21.407) for more.

With all the above having been said, since you're actually paginating Tables, I strongly suspect the most reliable way that you're going to get this to work is by using some of the flying saucer Render Engine CSS for pagination that's related to Tables. Doing that would require you to encapsulate your entire page in a Table and then use before table page break and after table page break attributes in your CSS.

Comment: Thank you for responding.I have changed the version to 4.2 and the following syntax.But it doesn't work fine.Image is not getting displayed.

Comment: I tried it.Image is not getting  displayed.It gets displayed only with this code:<apex:image url="{!$Resource.IconAji}"  width="220" height="150" />.But I want it to be displayed in every page of the PDF.So this code won't work out for this.

Comment: Thank you.With your code,Image gets displayed,but only in the first page not in every page.

Comment: Try enclosing your css in @media print tags to see if that doesn't resolve your issue. I suspect it doesn't know there's any pagination going on.

Comment: It is not working.Can you help me with this?

Comment: You're going to need to post your exact code and tell me more as to "what isn't working" that you're trying to accomplish. If you're using a custom controller, please post that code as well.

Comment: Thank you.I have updated the code.Image is getting displayed only in the first page of PDF.I want it to be displayed in all the pages.Can you please help me in doing this?

Comment: Three questions. 1. Are your page counters working? 2. Is there a reason you need the `<apex:pageblock>`s and `<apex:pageblocksection>`s, such as for styling as opposed to using divs or nested tables? Finally: 3. Are your tables wrapping across pages and being split? Also, as I told you before, get rid of the `docType="html-5.0"` as that's not going to work.

Comment: Thank you.Yes Page counters are working fine.I need page block and page block section without which it can't work.Yeah now I have removed doc-type 5.0 which had no effect in my output.

Comment: Thank you so much.Both the code didn't work.Image itself was not displayed.Thanks Much for supporting this way long.

Comment: I really don't know what else to tell you unless you totally switch to tables. If you do and enclose everything in an outer table, there's css syntax to get the table header to display at the top of each page when it paginates. In all honesty, I strongly suspect the root of your issue is the visualforce tags you have in your code for pageblocks, etc. Remove them and replace with divs then I'd expect your issues will likely go away.

Comment: I will work on it and update soon.Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this to show images on PDF page:

```
<p><apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles, '/Images/CompanyLogo.png')}" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="250" height="80"/></p>
```

**style** tag doesn't work well with PDF pages, I'd suggest to use inline styling instead.

Comment: Thank You.Yeah even I have used the same but I need the header image to be visible in every other page of the PDF.